# Play-ReactiveMongo plugin: play2 testing a controller with a reactiveMongoApi

Tags: mongodb, testing, playframework, reactivemongo

In the following, I am using the Play2 ReactiveMongo plugin in version 0.11.0.play24 (https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo)
for Play 2.4.

As mentioned in the documentation located at http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/play2.html, a Play2 controller with Mongo is instantiated as follows:

```
class MyController @Inject() (val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi)
extends Controller with MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents { }
```

Therefore, since the controller is now a class and not an object, it is not possible to use it as a singleton in the test cases.

However, I do not know how to inject the reactiveMongoApi in order to instantiate a MyController() with the right parameters in a test case (ScalaCheck or other...)

Do you have any idea/example on how to test such a controller with ScalaCheck or Specs2?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can produce a mock for `ReactiveMongoApi` (depending which mock framework you use):

```
val reactiveMongoApi = mock[ReactiveMongoApi]
```

and then you can do this:

```
new MyController(reactiveMongoApi)
```

That's the simplest approach.  To use the actual `ReactiveMongoApi` object:

```
val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
  .in(Mode.Test)
  .configure("play.modules.enabled" -> "play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule")
  .build

val reactiveMongoApi = app.injector.instanceOf[ReactiveMongoApi]
```

If it gets more complicated, for example, partially mocked nested dependency tree (this is more integration testing than unit testing), you may want to partially mock the Guice framework as explained [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice).

Comment: Thank you @bjfletcher for your prompt answer! If I mock the reactiveMongoApi however, I will not be able to interact with a local MongoDB instance? Is there any other alternative then? Thank you!

Comment: Unit testing with a real database - you're dangerous in my book. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, you are right this is not a good solution. This is due to the fact that it is not possible to embed a MongoDB instance for unit tests (the existing solutions are not maintained, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This project use Guice for dependency injection, Spec2 for testing controllers, and Frisby for testing endpoints.

https://github.com/luongbalinh/play-mongo